# Compare two columns in QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, sql

I have two columns in QGIS attribute table:

```
column A = street name
column B = Building type [Residential or Commercial]
```

what I am trying to do is get `"street name"` with the highest number of `"Commercial"` Building Type.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Don't think this is possible to do in the attribute table. You may need to use the **GroupStats** plugin to calculate the `Count` for each `"street name"`, export the results as a csv and then do a **Join** with the shapefile and the csv file.